# How do I print the first row from a list of lists?

Tags: python

I'm using python 3 and using data from a .tseries file.

Here's the code I wrote to section out the dates. Now I want to just print the first date listed. There's a picture of what I get. I can't figure it out.

```
for i in lines:
    line = ( (i.split('        ')))
    line = line[:1]
    print (line)
```

Comment: Could you add a sample of the `.tseries` file please?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what the tseries file format is but this could be a problem with tabs or the number of whitespaces you are splitting on.

How about:

```py
import re
for i in lines:
    print(re.split('\s+',line)[:1])
```